# lipis/flag-icons weird character in production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, country-flag-icons

I use the lipis/flag-icons library in my vite project and I get a weird character over my flags, but only in production:

```
.fi:before {
    content: "Â ";
}
```

```
.fi-it.fis {
    background-image: url(/assets/it-03086f2e.svg);
}
```

```
.fi {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.333333em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

This is what I get in the browser, the Â character. What's happening? I did the installation correctly and imported:

import "/node_modules/flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css";